# jquery DataTables zeroRecords

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using Datatables 1.10 with server side filtering everything works fine but i need something to add to it. Currently i have this code.

```
$('#myTable').dataTable({
    "language":
    {
        "zeroRecords": "No records match",
    }
});
```

I need to show a label whenever the datatable does not have value after filtering or `zeroRecords` in datatables.

**EDIT**

```
var oTable = $('#transactionHistoryDataTable').dataTable({

            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "api/Sitecore/Account/DataProviderAction",
            "bProcessing": true,
            "aoColumns": [
                            { "sName": "Date", "bSortable": false },
                            { "sName": "Name", "bSortable": false },
                            { "sName": "Activity", "bSortable": false },
            ],
            "sDom": '<"top">tip',

            "fnServerParams": function (aoData, fnCallback) {
                aoData.push({ "name": "ActivityParam", "value": $('#activityList').val() });
                aoData.push({ "name": "dateFrom", "value": $('#dateFrom').val() });
                aoData.push({ "name": "dateTo", "value": $('#dateTo').val() });
            },
            "language": {
                "loadingRecords": "Loading...",
                "zeroRecords": "<span class='label label-danger' >You have no activity for the selected Period</span>",
                "sEmptyTable": (function (oSettings, json) {
                    if ($('#transactionHistoryDataTable').find('tbody tr').length <= 1) {
                        $('#transactionHistoryDataTable').parent().hide();
                        $('div.filters > a, #tableheader').hide();
                        $('#message').text('There are no transactions to display.');
                    }       
                })
            },
            "drawCallback": function (settings) {
                if (settings._iRecordsTotal === 0)
                    $('#temp').show();
                else
                    $('#temp').hide()
            }
        });
```

html

```
<span class='label label-danger' style="display:none;" id="temp">No records found</span>
```

Comment: try this : `"zeroRecords": "<span class='label label-danger' >No records found</span>"`  . you can add html to `zeroRecords`

Comment: it works thanks. but what if the label is outside the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the comment

> it works thanks. but what if the label is outside the table?

If you have

```
<span class='label label-danger' style="display:none;" id="temp">No records found</span>
```

outside the table, then do this

```
$('#transactionHistoryDataTable').on('draw.dt', function() {
    if ($(this).DataTable().data().length==0) {
        $("#temp").show();
    }    
})
```

- place it before your dataTable() initialisation
- the DataTable() "typecast" is only to be able to use the more easier API

Comment: Are you sure this event works when there are zero records? Because I tried it and I got this error TypeError: data is undefined

Comment: I solved this use. My data was incorrect. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

try this

HTML

```
<span class='label label-danger' style="display:none;" id="temp">No records found</span>
```

JS

```
var oTable =$('#myTable').DataTable({
    "language":
    {
        "zeroRecords": "No records match",
    }
}); 
oTable.on('draw', function () {                  
    if (oTable.settings()[0]._iRecordsTotal === 0)
       $('#temp').show();
    else
       $('#temp').hide()
});
```

Note: See the difference in `DataTable` function name. `D` is capital.Your version supports this capital `D`

If you want to achieve this with small `d` then use this

**Approach 1**

```
var oTable =$('#myTable').dataTable({
    "language":
    {
        "zeroRecords": "No records match",
    },
    "drawCallback": function (settings) {
        if (settings._iRecordsTotal === 0)
            $('#temp').show();
        else
            $('#temp').hide()
    }
 });
```

**Approach 2**

```
$('#myTable').on('draw.dt', function () {
    if (oTable.fnSettings()._iRecordsTotal === 0)
        $('#temp').show();
    else
        $('#temp').hide()
});
```

Comment: it does not work. i also can't use the capital D because other function like `fnDraw` and  `fnFilter` does not work with capital D

Comment: still not working. i've also tried changing `settings` to `oSettings` , `drawCallback` to `fnDrawCallback` and `iRecordsTotal` to `fnRecordsTotal` none of them work

Comment: can you provide a fiddle ? for me its working with small `d` and `drawCallback`

Comment: update the id of the `label` . i used `temp` in my code . you used `myLabel` for the label  in your html .

Comment: put an alert in my code and check whether it is executing or not. thats the last option i got